# Tunnel over HTTP Server

Tags: networking, vpn, http, tunneling

As you know, in many countries censorships are prevents us to reach some sites.

In Turkey, there will be censorships on Facebook and Youtube.

I thought It will be great to pass these censorships over HTTP server.

Is there any scripts or applications which may allow us to use HTTP server like a tunnel?

Or, how can I implement it, what will I use?

We will rent a server with unlimited traffic and use it 5-10 people just for tunneling.

Comment: Just setup a VPN but use 80/443 instead of the default port

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/63929/tunnel-over-https-proxy-server-client-server-model?rq=1 and the softwares: corkscrew and proxytunnel.

Comment: Are sympathetic as I am to your situation, you are asking us to assist you in circumnavigating the restrictions our peers have implemented. This is explicitly [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use OpenVPN. If you use a OpenVPN server listening on port 443, it will probably not be filtered. However, people analyzing your network traffic will know that you are using OpenvPN: you might want to avoid this.

If you want to avoid this, you could connect to the OpenVPN server through a HTTPS proxy. OpenVPN knows how to use a HTTP proxy but not a HTTPs one so you have to use a tool such as socat:

- use socat on localhost to forward to a HTTPS proxy (deployed near the OpenVPN server);

  socat TCP-LISTEN:9999,bind=localhost OPENSSL:proxy.example.com:443
- ask OpenVPN to use the localhost as a HTTP proxy.

OpenVPN -(HTTP proxy)-> local proxy unwrapper -(TLS)-> HTTP proxy -(OpenVPN/TCP)-> OpenVPN Server

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use PPP over SSL:

```
socat OPENSSL:ppp.example.com:443 EXEC:"sudo pppd nodetach noipdefault notty noauth 192.168.0.1:198.169.0.2"
```

or PPP over HTTPS proxy:

```
socat EXEC:"corkscrew www.exmaple.com 443 ppp.example.com 9999" EXEC:"sudo pppd nodetach noipdefault notty noauth 192.168.0.1:198.169.0.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might setup a SSH tunnel and use ProxyCommand with corscrew to relay it to a HTTPs (or plain TLS) proxy:

```
ssh ssh.example.com
```

With:

```
 Tunnel point-to-point
 ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy proxyport %h %p
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want people to access websites, the simpler solution is probably to setup a 
CONNECT capable) HTTPs proxy.